# Run jar files - FlowDroid on mac terminal

Tags: java, macos, jar, classpath

I need to run a Java lib called [FlowDroid](https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/wiki) in the Mac terminal.
I followed the documents and download the nighty build version of FlowDroid project.
After that, I use the commands that provided in the website but it does not work.

```
java -cp soot.jar;soot-infoflow.jar;soot-infoflow-android.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar; slf4j-       simple-1.7.5.jar;axml-1.0.jar soot.jimple.infoflow.android.TestApps.Test "D:\Callbacks_Button1.apk" D:\Tools\AndroidSDK\sdk\platforms
```

I think it is a Java classpath problem, but I cannot figure it out. Whats wrong with the above commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't have your exact error, that's pretty difficult to help. Anyway, on Mac OS X you should use the `:` as a classpath separator instead of `;` which is for Windows systems.

Your command line should then look like:

```
java -cp soot.jar:soot-infoflow.jar:soot-infoflow-android.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar:axml-1.0.jar soot.jimple.infoflow.android.TestApps.Test "D:\Callbacks_Button1.apk" D:\Tools\AndroidSDK\sdk\platforms
```